# Writing to the application event log

Tags: c#

[image]  I am trying to write my website exceptions to the application event log and I tried       different ways and  I saw so many postings but still I am not able to do that. Please anyone help me in trying to do this. Here is my code

```
public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute

{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        {
            // Bail if we can't do anything; app will crash.
            if (filterContext == null)
                return;
            // since we're handling this, log to ELMAH(Error logging modules and handler)

            var ex = filterContext.Exception ?? new Exception("No further information exists.");
            WriteToEventLog(ex);

            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            var data = new ErrorPresentation
            {
                ErrorMessage = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ex.Message),
                TheException = ex,
                ShowMessage = filterContext.Exception != null,
                ShowLink = false
            };

           filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                                      {
                                          ViewName = "~/Views/Home/ErrorPage.aspx"
                                      };
         }
    }

    public void WriteToEventLog(Exception exception)
    {
        // todo : now I need to write this exception to Event log

        String cs = "FailureAudit";
        var thisMachineName = "abc";
        var logName = "Application";

        EventLog eventLog = new EventLog(logName, thisMachineName);
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(logName))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(logName, logName);

        }
        eventLog.Source = cs;
        eventLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        //eventLog.WriteEntry( exception.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        eventLog.WriteEntry(exception.ToString());

    }
}
```

Comment: `EventLog.CreateEventSource(logName, logName);` needs administrative rights...
But you could post your error to get us on the right track

Comment: BTW. i think NLog supports EventLog as Target.

Comment: I have all permissions and I am looged in as administrator only still I am getting the same error

Comment: Is your web application running as Administrator, too?

Comment: The way Windows UAC works is you might be logged in as administrator, but by default when you start a program, it runs as a non-admin user unless the program requests admin rights.

Comment: You can use this to test your rights.

`EventLogPermission permission = new EventLogPermission(EventLogPermissionAccess.Administer, ".");
            permission.Assert();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the below cmd (with administrative rights) on my machine and I can write to application eventlog now

```
eventcreate /ID 1 /L APPLICATION /T INFORMATION /SO MYSOURCE /D "MY-SOURCE"
```

Thanks for the suggestions and comments.

Comment: This command creates the log and insert a first information line.  After that it isn't needed anymore.  People who is releasing installation packages should put something similar in their scripts.